# Cannot resolve symbol jaxws Apache cxf

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I have this piece of code in my project

```
Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(((org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl)dispSOAPMsg).getBinding());
```

and on `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl`i get "Cannot resolve symbol". However, I should have imported needed libraries, in my pom I have

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

which should be needed dependency, but looks like I still miss it. Do I need to use different dependency?

EDIT: [Why do I need to cast](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/adding-interceptors-to-a-dynamic-jax-ws-dispatcher-client-td5723001.html) is said here. I need to cast it to client to be able to apply ws security on it.

Comment: Did you build/clean your project after add the dependency?

Comment: Yes, i did rebuild and i did clean/compile with maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was problem of IntelliJ. Invalidate caches and restart did the job.

Comment: A little bit off topic, but if someone would be solving same thing, this will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance` as well. Use this instead: `Client client = ((DispatchImpl)dispSOAPMsg).getClient();`

Comment: Tried that multiple times, doesn't work. Invalidated everything, cleared every cache, re-imported the project a dozen times... it builds without issue but intellij keeps telling me it cannot resolve "jaxws"...